# ¿Como modificar las lineas de un archivo txt en java?

Tags: java, archivo

Tengo un dilema que no puedo solucionar. Resulta que tengo un archivo de texto que guarda información de los usuarios, cada linea del archivo corresponde a un usuario y sus atributos están separados por #.

> id#pass#td#saldo

Entonces así se quedaría el archivo (obviamente no son 3 usuarios, son 50 usuarios, es decir 50 lineas):

> 01#hola111#cc#100.0
>
> 02#hola122#ps#110.0
>
> 03#hola133#di#120.0

Cómo hago para modificar un atributo de la linea x dentro del archivo;

Ejemplo: quiero cambiar el saldo del usuario 02 en el archivo.

Nota: las lineas no son iguales, el tamaño de la linea varia de acuerdo a sus atributos (el único atributo que mantiene el tamaño es la id que es un string único de 5 letras).

Cómo lo hago?
Gracias.

Comment: 1) Lees el archivo, 2) separas los atributos por `#`, 3) Modificas el atributo, 4) Juntas los atributos con `#` 5) Escribes los datos de vuelta al archivo.  O, usas una base de datos en vez de un archivo.

Comment: Añadiendo al comentario anterior, después de leer el archivo lo puedes leer con BufferedReader, while..readLine, separas las lineas y si tienes un ID de 5, ese puedes usar para identificar el usuario a modificar.Vas leyendo y llamando a un BufferedWriter para escribir tu archivo modificado ...

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda. Cualquier cosa que puedan añadir estaré agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo que investigues todo sobre los Streams / archivos
no entendí bien la pregunta, pero para poder insertar caracteres a un txt con java puedes utilizar la clase **Filewriter** que es la que se encarga de insertar caracteres te dejare un ejemplo:

```
File archivo = new File("ejemplo.txt"); // este es el archivo que insertaras caracteres
FileWriter escribir = new FileWriter(archivo);
String texto = "aqui van los caracteres a insertar";
for(int i=0; i<texto.length();i++){
escribir.write(texto.charAt(i));
escribir.close();
```

Espero y sea la que buscas. 
recuerda es para agregar caracteres a un archivo de texto saludos!

Comment: Gracias Oscar, anotado. Si quiero reemplazar una palabra o linea completa por otra dentro del archivo, ¿qué puedo usar?.

Comment: mira busque y encontré este enlace, es mejor que yo escribirte el codigo completo 

http://todoelmed.blogspot.mx/2012/05/manejo-de-archivos-o-ficheros-en.html

es en java

Comment: @mb0  lee el archivo y recorrelo, dentro del while hacer split para que te sea mas facil  encontrar el campo a editar, una vez editado lo escribes. while ((slinea = br.readLine()) != null) { logica}

Comment: Ya he podido encontrar la cadena y modificara, pero ahora tengo un problema, cuando la escribo me genera nuevas lineas junto a las antiguas, no cambia los datos antiguos, quedan hay.

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es volcar esas modificaciones a otro archivo (osea el mismo archivo pero modificado), despues borras el original y cambias de nombre el que generaste poniendole el nombre antiguo